# Hide tags on page load in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo, dom-events, jsp-tags

I've developed a web page where there are several struts tags. On page load, only one tag is shown while all other tags are hidden. This is by the `onLoad()` in the body tag that calls a Javascript function(`.style.display = 'none';`) to hide the tags initially.

But when the network speed is slow, when the page loads, there is a brief flicker between the tags being shown first and then hidden by the `onLoad()`'s Javascript call.

Is there an alternate to hide tags on load without seeing this flicker?

Answer (score 1):

Do a css that will hide the content

```
.style
{
    display: none;
}
```

Browsers wait for CSS before rendering. JavaScript is executed after full page load and domready normally. This is why sometimes you get flickers.

Comment: Glad helped you, remember, do as much as you can server side (preparing data) and css (styling) and only what is necessary client-side (JavaScript) !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use visibility attribute of the tags. That means you should hide your tags in html code rather than using JavaScript function.